# Equivalent to LIKE operator (in SOQL) in string method

Tags: shield-encryption, shield

Due to shield encryption, I have to get rid of any SOQL queries filtered with encrypted fields. Thought is to remove the filter from soql and validate the retrieved soql results against the searchKey using a string method. I am able to get replacements for = (->equals) and IN (->contains) operators but did not find any for LIKE operator. Could anyone please help me with any other way? Is this the efficient way of doing?

```
Select Id from Account where Name LIKE: searchKey
```

where searchKey is a string with wildcards

Please ignore any syntax errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a [Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods.htm#!):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('h.+o world');
String s = 'hello world';
if(p.matcher(s).matches()) {
  // Matched!
}
```

You'll need to learn about [Regular Expressions](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which are far more powerful than wildcards.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: @Kanikala You're welcome!